# changing variables for use in defining vertices

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

Hello I am trying to make an auto generating triangle strip that basically makes a big square of triangles.  but when I have everything seemingly setup correctly it wont work help!

```
void test() {
    glVertex2f(a, b);
    glVertex2f(c, d);
    cout << "successfully generated" << endl;
    cout << (a) << endl;
    cout << (b) << endl;
    cout << (c) << endl;
    cout << (d) << endl;
}

void renderFunction() {

if (base != 5) {
    ++base;
    c - 0.2;
    d - 0.2;
    a - 0.2;
    b - 0.2;
    test();
}

}
```

I call renderFunction() in the glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)
what im basically trying to do is subtract everything by 0.2 so that it generates a new vertex to the left.  I know im missing something but idk what.  this is just a snippet of my code if you need more just ask.

CONSOLE OUTPUT:

successfully generated
0.2
0.2
-0.2
-0.2
successfully generated
0.2
0.2
-0.2
-0.2
successfully generated
0.2
0.2
-0.2
-0.2
successfully generated
0.2
0.2
-0.2
-0.2

Comment: `c - 0.2;` etc. has no side effects because the value is not stored anywhere.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine why wont it affect the variable aleady defined?            float a = 0.2;
float b = 0.2;
float c = -0.2;
float d = -0.2;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statements line `c - 0.2;` have no effect because the result is not stored anywhere. If you want to store the result into `c`, change it to `c -= 0.2;`